# Need help in update JSON attributes from different flow file in Apache NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I want to update an attribute in a JSON file with the value i get from other processor. Below is my Original JSON file.

```
{
 "applicant": {
        "applicant-id": null
        "full-name": "Tyrion Lannister",
        "mobile-number" : "8435739739",
        "email-id" : "tyrionlannister_casterlyrock@gmail.com"
    },
    "product": {
        "product-category" : "Credit Card",
        "product-type" : "Super Value Card - Titanium"
    }
}
```

Below is my EvaluavateJsonPath Config where I extracted the *applicant-id* attribute.

[image]

Below is my GenerateFlowFile processor which generate an id value.

[image]

Now I need the update the *applicant-id* attribute with the value (899872120) in the Original JSON as below.

```
{
 "applicant": {
        "applicant-id": 899872120
        "full-name": "Tyrion Lannister",
        "mobile-number" : "8435739739",
        "email-id" : "tyrionlannister_casterlyrock@gmail.com"
    },
    "product": {
        "product-category" : "Credit Card",
        "product-type" : "Super Value Card - Titanium"
    }
}
```

I tried to use MergeContent to merge the 2 flows and i can see the *Applicant-Id* attribute value in the flow file after the MergeContent processor. I tried using UpdateAttribue to update *Applicant-Id* but i'm not able get the update JSON record.

Below is my MergeContent Configuration.

[image]

Is there anything i'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

As of NiFi 1.2.0, the [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) processor supports NiFi Expression Language, so if you have your id value in the attribute "Applicant-id", you can use it in a *Default* JOLT spec:

```
{
  "applicant": {
    "applicant-id": "${Applicant-id}"
  }
}
```

That should transform your input JSON to your desired output JSON.

Comment: Thanks Mat. But we are using 1.1.0 version in our Environment. Is there anyway we can do in that version?

Comment: You should be able to use ReplaceText to match "application-id": null and replace it with "application-id": ${Application-id}.  This is a more fragile but should work fine for your input.